# Having trouble with Linux Sort command on date field separated with dash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Here's the text file I want to sort by HIREDATE:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   HIREDATE    SAL
7369    SMITH   17-DEC-1980 800
7499    ALLEN   20-FEB-1981 1600
7521    WARD    22-FEB-1981 1250
7566    JONES   02-APR-1981 2975
7654    MARTIN  28-sept-81  1250
7698    BLAKE   01-MAY-1981 2850
7782    CLARK   09-juin-81  2450
7788    SCOTT   19-APR-1987 3000
7839    KING    17-nov-81   5000
7844    TURNER  08-sept-81  1500
7876    ADAMS   23-MAY-1987 1100
7900    JAMES   3-DEC-1981  950
7902    FORD    03-DEC-1981 3000
7934    MILLER  23-janv-82  1300
```

I want to do via command line so no scripting.
I've tried:
`sort -k3.8n -k3.4,3.6M -k3.1,3.2n emp.txt`

which's supposed to sort the years, months and days according to their lengths

Comment: What program generated this file? No French locale (I have BE, CA, CH, FR, LU; I assume that's all available) seems to understand `juin` and `janv` as month abbreviations.

Comment: actually it's a school work that seems impossible

Comment: Not impossible, but you'll need to sanitize those dates first :/

Answer (score 1):

1: Sanitizing

```
sed -i 's/sept-81 /SEP-1981/g;s/juin-81 /JUN-1981/g;s/nov-81  /NOV-1981/g;s/janv-82 /JAN-1982/g;s/ 3-DEC-1981 / 03-DEC-1981/g' textfile
```

2: Sorting

```
cat textfile | tail +2 | awk '{print $3,$2,$1,$4}' | sort -t- -k1.11n -k1.4,1.6M -k1.1,1.2n | awk '{print $3,$2,$1,$4}'
```

3: Output

```
7369 SMITH 17-DEC-1980 800
7499 ALLEN 20-FEB-1981 1600
7521 WARD 22-FEB-1981 1250
7566 JONES 02-APR-1981 2975
7698 BLAKE 01-MAY-1981 2850
7782 CLARK 09-JUN-1981 2450
7844 TURNER 08-SEP-1981 1500
7654 MARTIN 28-SEP-1981 1250
7839 KING 17-NOV-1981 5000
7902 FORD 03-DEC-1981 3000
7900 JAMES 03-DEC-1981 950
7934 MILLER 23-JAN-1982 1300
7788 SCOTT 19-APR-1987 3000
7876 ADAMS 23-MAY-1987 1100
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `date` command supports `-d` option, how about:

```
tail -n +2 emp.txt | while read -r line; do read -ra ary <<< "$line"; printf "%s\t%s\n" $(date +%s -d "${ary[2]}") "$line"; done | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

Result:

```
7369    SMITH   17-DEC-1980     800
7499    ALLEN   20-FEB-1981     1600
7521    WARD    22-FEB-1981     1250
7566    JONES   02-APR-1981     2975
7698    BLAKE   01-MAY-1981     2850
7782    CLARK   09-jun-81       2450
7844    TURNER  08-sept-81      1500
7654    MARTIN  28-sept-81      1250
7839    KING    17-nov-81       5000
7900    JAMES   3-DEC-1981      950
7902    FORD    03-DEC-1981     3000
7934    MILLER  23-jan-82       1300
7788    SCOTT   19-APR-1987     3000
7876    ADAMS   23-MAY-1987     1100
```

Not that I've also assumed `juin` and `janv` are typos for `jun` and `jan`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: they aren't typos, both English and French months are included

Comment: Oops, sorry for that. Then it may be out of my hand.